# Query returns incorrect result in SQL Server when it has special Chinese

Tags: sql, sql-server

DB:

```
create table Test 
(
     name nvarchar(200),
     lastName nvarchar(200),
     [Key] nvarchar(200)
)
```

Data:

```
insert into Test values (N'倩', N'䵧', N'Code123')
```

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Test 
WHERE lastName = ''
```

Result:

```
name     lastName    Key

倩       䵧           Code123
```

Why does it return this result? Because my condition is `lastName = ''`, it should return nothing. Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: i tried on my DB, it doesn't return anything with that select statement. What is your collation ?

Comment: You will need to tell us what type of SQL server you are using.

Comment: im using sql server 2008 r2 guys and i can replicate it

Comment: i guess you must be using the default "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS". I am not expert on collation and i can't explain that. But for storing chinese character, i would use a Chinese collation.

Comment: @Squirrel, My DB's collation is 'Chinese_PRC_CI_AS'

Comment: @AJNeufeld SQL SERVER 2012

Answer (score 1):

It's the collation that messes the results.

```
select * from test where lastName= N'' COLLATE Chinese_Simplified_Stroke_Order_100_CI_AS;
```

Please take a look of this article

[Compare unicodes](http://www.siao2.com/2005/01/18/355210.aspx)